# Effect of the horizontal magnifier control on the sweep speed, sweep time and number of cycles observed?

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, voltage-measurement, frequency-measurement

What is the effect of the horizontal magnifier control on the sweep speed, sweep time and number of cycles observed?

Sweep speed increases by ten times for a 10X magnifier, sweep time reduces by the same and the number of cycles observed will be more.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

A horizontal magnifier on an oscilloscope is designed to decrease the sweep speed to allow better viewing of high speed signals   For example, assume the sweep speed is 1 usec/division.  Applying the 10X horizontal magnifier will decrease the sweep speed to 0.1 usec/division (It  multiplies the horizontal gain to achieve this). Thus you will see less cycles of your signal but at a higher sweep speed so you can see more details.

Comment: The horizontal magnifier INCREASES the sweep speed, so one cycle of the signal occupies a wider protion of the screen that without the magnifier.  0.1 uSec/div is faster than 1 uSec/div.

Answer (score 1):

A 10x magnifier will not affect the number of sweeps performed.  It will increase the rate at which the beam (or simulated beam) moves across the screen, but depending upon how the horizontal position is adjusted there will be some delay between a trigger event and when the beam starts moving across the screen, or between the time the beam leaves the right edge and the scope becomes ready for the next event.  One of the reasons for using a 10x zoom instead of simply selecting a faster time base is that if one has the trigger delay and hold-off controls adjusted to capture just the events one is interested in, engaging 10x zoom won't affect what events get captured.  By contrast, changing the time base by a factor of 10 would likely result in it the scope triggering at unwanted times.